# Привязка элементов внутри элемента с другой привязкой

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Возникла следующая проблема.

Есть 2 ObservableCollection: это `EmpList` и `AbsCatList`. DataGrid привязывается к `EmpList` и показывает оттуда данные. Внутри грида есть ComboBox, который хранит данные из `AbsCatList`. Но его тег необходимо указать из `EmpList`.
И вопрос заключается в следующем, как в ComboBox показывать данные из `AbsCatList`, а указать его тег - из `EmpList`?

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <viewmodel:EmployerList x:Key="emp"/>
        <viewmodel:AbsenceCategoryList x:Key="absCat"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="White">
        <DataGrid Name="TimeSheetGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource emp}}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EmpList}"
                  SelectedValuePath="EmpID">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EmpName}" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>Тип</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="230" IsReadOnly="True" 
                                      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource absCat}}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AbsCatList}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                                      Tag="{Binding Path=EmpList, ElementName=EmpID}" 
                                      SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: А зачем вообще вам нужен Tag? Их никто нигде не использует. Опишите задачу человеческими словами, покажите модели данных, расскажите, что хотите получить на экране. Пока выглядит так, что вы не туда забрели и пытаетесь [забивать гвозди микроскопом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567).

Comment: У вас тут на мой взгляд 2 основные проблемы: 1. `<viewmodel:EmployerList x:Key="emp"/>` - это нарушение MVVM, не стоит так делать, ибо View слой не должен знать про ViewModel, и тем более, отвечать за срок жизни VM и создавать его. 2. `DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource absCat}}"` - вы постоянно задаете `DataContext`, когда ваше приложение должно базироваться на одном, заданном главному окну, все, дальше все по цепочки подтянется сами. Ну и как вам сказали выше, `Tag` - это костыль, который говорит, прям кричит, что вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: @aepot моя задача - получить `SelectedValue` по возможности из ComboBox, который находится внутри DataGrid, чтобы в дальнейшем взаимодействовать с данными.